# A "/" appears at the end of my URL when I try to push using CMD, resulting in error 403

Tags: git, github

Whenever I try to push my project to my repo using CMD, I receive error: 
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Username/Repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`
I have viewed the names of the URL's with `git remote -v` which returns: 
`origin  https://github.com/Username/Repo.git (fetch)`
`origin  https://github.com/Username/Repo.git (push)`
You can see that there is no `/` at the end of the URL yet when I attempt a push it just adds one on anyway!
I tried to set the URL to not include the `/` with 
`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Username/Repo.git`, which seems to work but in actuality does nothing.
I'm not really sure what to do, because I am very very new to Git and GitHub... any help would be useful to me.

Comment: your access token is valid? (https://github.com/settings/tokens)

Comment: `403` is "access denied", i.e., they don't like you or don't believe you are who you claim to be and are telling you to go away. You'll need to figure out why they don't like you. (It's not the slash at the end, it's the user-name-and-password you're sending with your https connection. Look up "git credential helper". Note that while GitHub say that they require tokens instead of passwords, tokens are simply a specialized *kind* of password; Git credential helpers call that a "password".)